# In Visual Studio for MAC the xaml and xaml.cs files get separated rather than xaml.cs should be inside xaml file

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, maui, mobile-application

I am experiencing this happening randomly. Sometimes xaml files are appearing as they should for eg:

[image]

and sometimes they appear seperately for eg :

[image]

due to this in xaml.cs file I am not able to call the elememnts by their x:Name mentioned in xaml files.

has anyone also encountered this in Visual Studio for MAC

To resolve this what I did is opened my project in Visual Studios Windows and then changed the properties to MAUI XAML

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a difference between your two pictures that。Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)